# Building a software parrot repeater with Linux CLI audio-processing tools?

Tags: linux, alsa, sox, audio-processing

I have an audio coming from a radio transceiver on my sound card's microphone input. What i want to make is a simple software-based parrot repeater using Linux CLI tools like the `sox` suite and `arecord`. For it to work, i think a flow similar to the following must take place:

1. The audio that comes on the microphone subdevice is getting recorded in a buffer (file or RAM-based)
2. When the buffer stops filling (audio stopped), start playing it's content on the audio output device (it is connected to the radio's microphone input)
3. When it's over, empty the buffer and start expecting step 1 to occur again

I'm looking for an elegant way to implement the logic behind step 2. Is there a CLI tool that i can use for that, so i can pipe the microphone audio taken with `arecord` to it and `play` the output of the buffer with sox?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this. I did this on a raspberry pi a little while ago, only I made a voice changer.
https://www.instructables.com/Halloween-Voice-Changer-With-Raspberry-Pi/

Basically, `play "|rec --buffer 2048 -d"` takes recorded sound and puts it in a buffer that is passed in 4096 bit (byte?) chunks to play. `-d` stands for duration, and if left blank defaults to 0, and will run until killed. If you want to play with the options, there is some helpful info in the links.

Good luck with your project!